# unsigned shift template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to do an unsigned shift in C++. Here's my example code. The problem with it is it isn't generic. This code is completely wrong. It will not work on longs and it wont work on smaller types like char. I tried `(unsigned T)` but that is a syntax error. How might i make this generic without specialization?

```
#include <cassert>
template<class T>
T unsigned_shift(const T&t, int s) { return ((unsigned int)t)>>s; }
int main()
{
    assert(unsigned_shift(-1, 2)==(-1u>>2));
    assert(unsigned_shift((char)-1, 2)==64);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), the [type_traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) library has the [`make_unsigned`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/make_unsigned.html) template that would fit your needs perfectly.

```
#include <boost/type_traits/make_unsigned.hpp>

template<class T>
T unsigned_shift(const T&t, unsigned int s)
{
    return ((make_unsigned<T>::type)t)>>s;
}
```

(I changed the type of `s` to `unsigned int` because the operation of the shift operators is undefined for negative values of the second operand - see §5.8 ¶1)

Comment: I am unsure if i can use boost but i looked at the code and it appears i MUST use specialization. I'll accept later as i am hoping a C++0x person can add in another answer (if another exist)

Comment: @acidzombie24 `std::make_[un]signed` is coming with C++0x, inside `<type_traits>`. Their specification are similar to the Boost traits. As a final note, remember that the final (implicit) conversion from unsigned to T when returning is implementation defined when T is signed.

Answer (score 0):

What about casting to `unsigned long` to do the shift and then casting back to `T` to return it?

Also in a normal twos complement wouldn't the result of the second shift would be 63 not 64?

Comment: oh right it would be 63. However casting -1 to unsigned long would have all the bits set thus >>1 would still be -1.

Comment: An unsigned with all 1's set is not negative. It's the largest possible value for that type.